# Minimize term without Karnaugh map

Tags: propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I have the following term, that should get minimized with Boolean algebra (no Karnaugh map!):

(a ∧ ¬b ∧ c) ∨ (a ∧ c ∧ d) ∨ (b ∧ d)

I already figured out, that the minimzed term is as follows (everything without the middle term) and it makes totally sense to me:

(a ∧ ¬b ∧ c) ∨ (b ∧ d)

However when I try to get same result with boolean algebra I am not able to reproduce it.

My first step is the following:

(a ∧ c) ∧ (¬b ∨ d) ∨ (b ∧ d)

When I apply distributivity-law I end up with the first (non-minimized) term.

Edit: Besides the question above, more general: Can every term that is minimizable by a Karnaugh map be minimized with boolean algebra?

Comment: What does KV mean?

Comment: The german abbreviation for the Karnaugh map... updated the question!

Comment: Where is the Boolean algebra? Looks like propositional logic to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
a\overline{b}c+acd+bd & = a\overline{b}c + acd(b+\overline{b}) + bd \\
& = a\overline{b}c + acdb+acd\overline{b} + bd \\
& = (a\overline{b}c + a\overline{b}cd) + (bd + bdac) \\
& = a\overline{b}c + bd \\
\end{align}